# Python update nested list and dicts with values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following schema I would like to update the values `contact` and `geo` with a base64 of the object values.

Example:

```
data = [{"country":"germany","details":[{"state":"BR","location_details":[{"zipcode":"49875","contact":[{"contact_information":["a@ger.org"],"type":"email","phone":"444-44-4444"},{"contact_information":["b@ger.org"],"type":"email","phone":"555-44-4444"}],"geo":[{"center":["55.4"],"rotate":"50","parallels":"6000"},{"center":["55.4"],"rotate":"50","parallels":"6000"}]}]}]}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{"country":"germany","details":[{"state":"BR","location_details":[{"zipcode":"49875","contact":"W3tjb250YWN0X2luZm9ybWF0aW9uOlthQGdlci5vcmddLHR5cGU6ZW1haWwscGhvbmU6NDQ0LTQ0LTQ0NDR9LHtjb250YWN0X2luZm9ybWF0aW9uOltiQGdlci5vcmddLHR5cGU6ZW1haWwscGhvbmU6NTU1LTQ0LTQ0NDR9XQo=","geo":"W3tjZW50ZXI6WzU1LjRdLHJvdGF0ZTo1MCxwYXJhbGxlbHM6NjAwMH0se2NlbnRlcjpbNTUuNF0scm90YXRlOjUwLHBhcmFsbGVsczo2MDAwfV0K"}]}]}]
```

though I want to do this dynamically, this list grows big and I want to be able to do update those fields. and rebuild the same schema object again with the substituted values.

Code:

```
import base64
for flat_data in data:
    for detail in data.get("details"):
        for location_detail in detail.get("location_details"):
            _contact = base64.b64encode(location_detail.get("paths"))
            _geo = base64.b64encode(location_detail.get("geo"))
```

**Update**: I want to emphasize that I need to rebuild the same schema object again with the substituted values! also, `data` can have multiple objects within the list.

Comment: What's your code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even start asking why^^
I call your monster `x`:

```
x = [{"country":"germany",
      "details":[{"state":"BR",
                  "location_details":[{"zipcode":"49875",
                                       "contact":[{"contact_information":["a@ger.org"],"type":"email","phone":"444-44-4444"},
                                                  {"contact_information":["b@ger.org"],"type":"email","phone":"555-44-4444"}],
                                       "geo":[{"center":["55.4"],"rotate":"50","parallels":"6000"},
                                              {"center":["55.4"],"rotate":"50","parallels":"6000"}]}]}]}]
```

This is a way to encode the part you want with base64:

```py
import base64

# You need to convert your object to bytes
# Here, I printed it to a string and converted that to bytes,
# but there are other options,
# I can't really tell *why* you are doing it, so it is
# hard to say how to encode. 
z = str(x[0]['details'][0]['location_details'][0]['contact']).encode('utf-8')

# Bytes to base64 encoded
out = base64.b64encode(z).decode('utf-8') 

print(out)
```

`json.dumps(...).encode('utf-8')` might also be an alternative for encoding.

#### Edit

Now for recreating your object, you have two options. Either you don't need the original data or you do need to keep it. For the former, it would look like

```
import base64

for data in x:
   for detail in data['details']:
        for location_details in detail['location_details']:
            z = str(location_details['contact']).encode('utf-8')
            out = base64.b64encode(z).decode('utf-8') 
            location_details['contact'] = out

            z2 = str(location_details['geo']).encode('utf-8')
            out2 = base64.b64encode(z2).decode('utf-8') 
            location_details['geo'] = out2

print(x)
```

If you do need the original data, then you do first

```
import copy
x2 = copy.deepcopy(x)
```

and work the with `x2`

Comment: First, thank you for that, second, I think you are assuming that x can have only one dict. but x can have multiple dicts x = [{}, {}]

Comment: Then just use the `for`-loops instead of `[0]`, which I saw you already figured out.

Comment: but how to rebuild the same schema object again with the substituted values dynamically! also, `data` can have multiple objects within the list.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by "rebuild the same schema object"?

Comment: Like I want the output to look exactly like this `[{"country":"germany","details":[{"state":"BR","location_details":[{"zipcode":"49875","contact":"W3tjb250YWN0X2luZm9ybWF0aW9uOlthQGdlci5vcmddLHR5cGU6ZW1haWwscGhvbmU6NDQ0LTQ0LTQ0NDR9LHtjb250YWN0X2luZm9ybWF0aW9uOltiQGdlci5vcmddLHR5cGU6ZW1haWwscGhvbmU6NTU1LTQ0LTQ0NDR9XQo=","geo":"W3tjZW50ZXI6WzU1LjRdLHJvdGF0ZTo1MCxwYXJhbGxlbHM6NjAwMH0se2NlbnRlcjpbNTUuNF0scm90YXRlOjUwLHBhcmFsbGVsczo2MDAwfV0K"}]}]}]
` not just outputing `_contact` and `_geo`

Comment: I'll update the answer, but you'll have to explain afterwards why that is not trivial ;)

Comment: Sure, yeah please update it and I will explain why it's not trivial .

Comment: Ok got it, I think that makes sense.  let me try it out, thanks

Comment: thanks, works, I think the thing I missed is how to return the data without modifying the original data, but you explained that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what's the purpose of doing this, but this code will do what you want.

First, you have some errors in your code, so it was fixed here.
Second, *b64encode()* method takes bytes as an argument, list won't get you bytes, so I converted the lists `location_detail.get("geo")` & `location_detail.get("geo")` to string.
To get the bytes from a string you simply use *encode()* method.

```
import base64

data = [{"country":"germany","details":[{"state":"BR","location_details":[{"zipcode":"49875","contact":[{"contact_information":["a@ger.org"],"type":"email","phone":"444-44-4444"},{"contact_information":["b@ger.org"],"type":"email","phone":"555-44-4444"}],"geo":[{"center":["55.4"],"rotate":"50","parallels":"6000"},{"center":["55.4"],"rotate":"50","parallels":"6000"}]}]}]}]

for flat_data in data:
    for detail in flat_data.get("details"):
        for location_detail in detail.get("location_details"):
            _contact = base64.b64encode(str(location_detail.get("contact")).encode())
            _geo = base64.b64encode(str(location_detail.get("geo")).encode())
```

**Output**

```
_geo = b'W3snY2VudGVyJzogWyc1NS40J10sICdyb3RhdGUnOiAnNTAnLCAncGFyYWxsZWxzJzogJzYwMDAnfSwgeydjZW50ZXInOiBbJzU1LjQnXSwgJ3JvdGF0ZSc6ICc1MCcsICdwYXJhbGxlbHMnOiAnNjAwMCd9XQ=='

_contact = b'W3snY29udGFjdF9pbmZvcm1hdGlvbic6IFsnYUBnZXIub3JnJ10sICd0eXBlJzogJ2VtYWlsJywgJ3Bob25lJzogJzQ0NC00NC00NDQ0J30sIHsnY29udGFjdF9pbmZvcm1hdGlvbic6IFsnYkBnZXIub3JnJ10sICd0eXBlJzogJ2VtYWlsJywgJ3Bob25lJzogJzU1NS00NC00NDQ0J31d'
```

Comment: That's not the output I'm expecting, I should rebuild the whole dict along with the modified values. how can I modify the values and return the whole dict "data" with the modifications?

Comment: What prevents you from just writing the modified data into the dict? After all it is a mutable object... Otherwise you might need `copy.deepcopy()`